# On Product Save from Magento admin getting the Integrity constraint violation error

Tags: magento-1.8, products, indexing, cataloginventory

On Product Save from Magento admin getting the Integrity constraint violation error, Can any one please let me know why this errors coming up.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '23100-1' `for key 'UNQ_CATALOGINVENTORY_STOCK_ITEM_PRODUCT_ID_STOCK_ID'`
```

Thanks.

Comment: do reindex from `system->indexmanagment` and try again

Comment: done but it is not happening, getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

I figure out the issue.

Notes:

Magento website is connected with store manager for product create/update, due to some unknown reason/configurations, some of the products got deleted from Magento website and index not happened properly.

Due to which some products left as **orphans** in **cataloginventory-stock-item** table.

When I checked the number of records in `catalog_product_entity` and `cataloginventory_stock_item` tables,  they differed in count.

```
select count(*) from catalog_product_entity
select count(*) from cataloginventory_stock_item
```

> I have taken the `cataloginventory_stock_item` table backup, truncated
>   the table and once again run the inventory index from terminal.

Index run successfully now and the count of the above two tables also got match and the issue of creating product from admin got resolved, as there are no more orphan records left in cataloginventory_stock_item table.